# Can't setText of a TextView using a String with data from db

Tags: java, android, string, textview, settext

I have a TextView and a String randomWord. When the app starts I open my db and call a method db.open() which opens it and then the db.randomize() which calls the randomize() method and queries the db for  random entry and returns it as a String. Thereafter I just want to MyTextView.setText (randomWord); but when app is running nothing is displaying. I have tried to hardcode in setText ("whatever") and that is shown.

So I guess I have done wrong in the randomize or something because I don't get a word from the db.

This is what I try to do:

```
 db.open();
        db.randomize(generatedWord);
        //text = new SpannableString(generatedWord);
        //text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, text.length(), 0);  
        wordHolder.setText("" + generatedWord);
        db.close();
```

This is my random method:

```
  public Cursor randomize(String word) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Cursor cursor;
            return cursor =  this.db.query("tblnames ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);
        }
```

My DB has two columns: "_id" and "word"

```
"create table tblnames (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
     + "words text not null);"
```

Can it have to do that I don't specify the _id and word somewhere in the randomize()?

ALSO: I tried setText (generatedWord) as well as setText (" +generatedWord);
ALSO: no errors while running.

Comment: the query is: return cursor =  this.db.query("tblnames ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);

Comment: the problem is that the randomize method dont get a random word from the dtabse, but null value. Why? Ive tried to put the KEY_ROWID, KEY_WORDS into the new String[] {KEY_ROW, KEY_WORDS} as well as only using KEY_WORDS because i only wnt the word and not the id. Maybe I should tryt o create a new DB with only Words and no _id?

Comment: Yes.  public Cursor randomize(String word) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Cursor cursor;
            return cursor =  this.db.query("tblnames ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning a String with your `randomize()` method.

This should give you the desired affect

```
db.open();
//text = new SpannableString(generatedWord);
//text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, text.length(), 0);  
wordHolder.setText(db.randomize());
db.close();
```

And in your DB you need to return the string value of the column you want from your cursor, not the cursor itself.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)

```
public String randomize() {
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor =  this.db.query("tblnames ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( "word" ));
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot. I am a hard beginner you see... Ill get to it rightaway!

Comment: When i tried to implement these changes and ran the app it shut down and im not very good of reading this LogCat but from what i can guess its a cursorindexoutofbounds that is making the error. What does this mean? does {"*"} have anything to do with it? Should i try to explicitly tell it {KEY_ROWID, KEY_WORDS} or maybe only {KEY_WORDS} - or is something else i need to check? IT SAYS Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: I did it myself actually! :) My solution was: public String randomize() {
  
  Cursor cursor = this.db.query("tblnames ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( "words" ));
  
 }

Comment: Sure, how? xD and can i ask you for one more thing?

Comment: now this is wrking in main.java and sets the fetched word to a spannablestring and to red color(just to see its working): db.open();
  text = new SpannableString(db.randomize());
  text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, text.length(), 0);  
  wordHolder.setText(text);
  db.close();

Comment: But not this one, which is caleld when  user presses Enter-button and my idea is then to capture lastinput (char) from user and send it to this method: (i think it is the text.charAt(lastInput) because there is where you are supposed to put START and END, but i dont know how, i want to insert the char wherever it matches the fetched word: 
 public void guess(char guess) {
  
  if (text.toString().indexOf(lastInput) != -1) {
   text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), text.charAt(lastInput), text.charAt(lastInput), 0); 
  } 
  // if all-show gameEnd();
  else {
   showImages();
  }
 }

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION FOR SHOWING WORD: instead of a spannable string (to hide and to show parts of the randomWord) i found StringBuilder, together with indexOf and userinput i was able to put in correct letters after a guess from the user. Like this:

```
public void guess()
    {
        char guess = userInput.getText().charAt(0);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(hiddenWord);
        String j = ""+guess;
        int index = randomedWord.indexOf(guess);

        if (randomedWord.contains(j))
        {
            while (index >= 0) 
            {
                builder.setCharAt(index*2, guess);
                index = randomedWord.indexOf(guess, index + 1);
                hiddenWord = builder.toString().trim();
                wordHolder.setText(hiddenWord);
                if (!(hiddenWord.toString().contains("_".toString())) )
                {
                    winner();
                }
            }   
        }
        else 
        {
            showImages();
        }
    }
```

SOLUTION FOR RANDOMWORD(generate it): just look at James answer, I had return the cursor itself on my DB and not the string value of the column i wanted which is the correct way

```
db.open();
wordHolder.setText(db.randomize());
db.close();

public String randomize() {
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor =  this.db.query("tblnames ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( "word" ));
    }
    return "";
}
```

FULL CODE:

// MainActivity.java

```
package com.emanuelolsson.simplehangman;

import database.DBAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HangMan extends Activity {

    // DECLARE NEEDED VARIABLES  
    private Button newGameButton, enterLetterButton;
    private EditText userInput;
    private TextView wordHolder;
    private ImageView imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree, imageFour, imageFive, imageSix, imageSeven, imageEight, winner, hanged;
    private String hiddenWord, randomedWord;
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hang_man);
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        // ASSIGN OBJECTS
        newGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newGame);
        enterLetterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
        wordHolder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordHolder);
        userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
        imageOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageTwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageThree = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageFour = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imageFive = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imageSix = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        imageSeven = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        imageEight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        winner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.winner);
        hanged = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hanged);
        imageOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageThree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSix.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSeven.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageEight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        hanged.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        wordHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        // ADD LISTENERS
        newGameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                newGame();

            }
        });

        enterLetterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (!(userInput.getText().toString().isEmpty()) )
                {
                    guess();
                } else if (userInput.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to insert a letter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
        db.open();
        db.fill();
        randomedWord = db.randomize();
        invWord();
        wordHolder.setText(hiddenWord);
        db.clear();
        db.close();
    }

    public void newGame() {
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        count = 0;
        imageOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageThree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSix.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSeven.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageEight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        hanged.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        db.open();
        db.fill();
        randomedWord = db.randomize();
        invWord();
        wordHolder.setText(hiddenWord);
        db.clear();
        db.close();
    }

    public void invWord() 
    {
        hiddenWord = randomedWord;
        hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replaceAll(".", "_" +" ");
    }

    public void guess()
    {
        char guess = userInput.getText().charAt(0);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(hiddenWord);
        String j = ""+guess;
        int index = randomedWord.indexOf(guess);

        if (randomedWord.contains(j))
        {
            while (index >= 0) 
            {
                builder.setCharAt(index*2, guess);
                index = randomedWord.indexOf(guess, index + 1);
                hiddenWord = builder.toString().trim();
                wordHolder.setText(hiddenWord);
                if (!(hiddenWord.toString().contains("_".toString())) )
                {
                    winner();
                }
            }   
        }
        else 
        {
            showImages();
        }
    }

    private void winner()
    {
        imageOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageThree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSix.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSeven.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageEight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    private void showImages() {

        count ++;

        if (count == 1) 
        {
            imageOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 2)
        {
            imageTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 3) 
        {
            imageThree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 4)
        {
            imageFour.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 5) 
        {
            imageFive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 6)
        {
            imageSix.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 7) 
        {
            imageSeven.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (count == 8)
        {   
            gameEnd();
        }

    }

    private void gameEnd() 
    {

        imageOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageTwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageThree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageFive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSix.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageSeven.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageEight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        hanged.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        wordHolder.setText(randomedWord);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hang_man, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

// XML

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picOne"
        android:src="@drawable/one" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picTwo"
        android:src="@drawable/two" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picThree"
        android:src="@drawable/three" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picFour"
        android:src="@drawable/four" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picFive"
        android:src="@drawable/five" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picSix"
        android:src="@drawable/six" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picSeven"
        android:src="@drawable/seven" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picEight"
        android:src="@drawable/eight" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/winner"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/winner"
        android:src="@drawable/winner" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hanged"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hanged"
        android:src="@drawable/hanged" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wordHolder"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/wordHolder"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/newGame" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/newGame"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/newGame"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/newGame"
        android:text="@string/enter" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userInput"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/enter"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="20dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@+id/header"
        android:src="@drawable/header" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It would be better with some explanation! ;) Please take the time to add them.